# setRetainInstance(boolean) method in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Its known from docs that `setRetainInstance(boolean)` method helps retains all active objects across device configuration changes, but most of the examples and documentations I read deals with headless fragments. Should we not use that method in fragments with UI elements. If not could any please give a detailed reason.

Comment: Its not like that, you can use setRetainInstance() method in the fragment which contains UI elements also.

Comment: It would be nice to link to the examples and docs you are referring to. Anyway, yes you can use `setRetainInstance` on Fragments with UI. Cf the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use headless fragments for background processing. Even if articles like this one: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments1 or this one: http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/ mention it.

Background processing should be done in a Service (alternatives exist but the question isn't about that). That's the component meant to do background processing while doing it in a headless fragment is a "loophole" (not the way Google meant fragments to be used).

Note: some devices don't retain the Fragment across a configuration change even with setRetainInstance(true). Using a headless fragment to run background tasks would obviously not work well on those devices.

setRetainInstance(true) is meant to be used with Fragments that have a ui to retain it across a configuration change. Very convenient if you use Loaders in a Fragment since the (expensive?) query won't re-run even if the Activity is destroyed and re-created.

Comment: so will `setRetainInstance(true)` do help in place of handling configuration changes which is usually handled through `onSaveInstanceState()` callback